# let P and Q be two non empty disjoint subset of R . which of the following is /are True ?

Tags: general-topology

let P and Q be  two non empty disjoint  subset of  R . which  of the following is /are True ?

a) If  $P $and $Q$ are  compact , then $P \cup Q $is  also  compact .

b) If  $P$ and $Q$ are not connected,then $P \cup Q$ is  also  not  connected .

I thinks both  a)  and b)  are  true...for  a )  i take  P= [0,1] and Q = [2,3]

for option b) i take P ={x}  and Q ={y}...where {x} and {y}  are  singleton
 sets...

is  my answer  is coorect or not ?? pliz tell me

Comment: (a) is true and does not necessitate an example, but rather a proof which is quite simple depending on the definition of compactness in $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: ok what about b) @Keen-ameteur

Comment: @Keen-ameteur Your $P=\{0\}$ is connected.

Comment: @Error404.  B is false.  See my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

b) is false. Let $A=(0,2)\cup \{2.5\}\setminus \{1\}$, $Q=[2,4)\cup \{1\}\setminus \{2.5\}$. Then $P \cup Q=(0,4)$ which is connected though $P$ and $Q$ are not.

Comment: But your $P$ and $Q$ are not disjoint.

Comment: @Error 404  I have edited my answer to make the sets disjoint.

Comment: Yes now it's good!

Comment: Z and R\Z or those sets intersected by an interval longer than two.

Answer (score 3):

A is correct.  Your proof is wrong because it requires looking
at all compact subsets of R.  You only looked at two.

B is false for all disconnected subsets of R even though there
are many examples of disconnected sets whose union is not
connected.  BTW, {x} and {y} are connected.

Q, the rationals, and P, the irrational are disconnected.
Is the union of P and Q disconnected?

Comment: ahh...How did I overlook that?